# Simple time-based chest push notification setup

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, onesignal

Hello I am trying to create a simple push-notification system similar to this common use case:
1. The user gets a chest and can either watch an ad to skip the wait time or wait one hours for the chest to open. The app sends an upstream request which sets up a downstream push notification that shall be delivered in one hour to let the user know the chest is ready.

2a. The user then waits an hour, gets a push notification (outside of the app) to open their chest and they do!

or

2b. They wait 20 minutes then decide to watch the ad. The app sends an upstream request which cancels the pending push notification which would have otherwise been delivered in 40 minutes.

Okay awesome so that is the problem and I am having a hard time understanding how to do this. I have looked over the documentation for each of these programs but they seem designed for downstream push notifications. It just seems odd there is no built-in support for this use case. It seems like such a common use case.

I so far found 3 solutions that will integrate into my cross-platform Unity setup and provide services for free or super-cheap:

1. Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)
2. Google Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
3. OneSignal
4. Amazon seems to group clients into "Topics" so I guess I would be setting up a one-device-topic and essentially. I can subscribe and unsubscribe from them but it doesn't seem to support a topic with a 60 minute delay.
   2a. Create a topic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-create-topic.html (it would just include the current device)
   2b. Subscribe to it
   2c. Send a message to it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-with-attributes.html
   So basically I can add attributes to my message but it would seem I need to implement the server-side code to read a delay attribute then somehow queue a message for delay. Maybe I am missing something?
5. For Firebase I pretty much see the same thing as Amazon. There are topics https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging and a means to send upstream messages https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-with-console but with the messages I don't see anyway here to get the time delay https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/topic-messaging I see conditions towards the bottom of that article but I don't know if it is meant for this use case.
6. OneSignal has the easiest to scroll-through API. I'll refer to some strings that you can CTRL-F by using the format ("Create Notif") because everything is on this one page: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference
   So basically I can ("Send to Specific Devices") which I guess would be the sending device, then I can ("Schedule notification for future delivery.") using the send_after parameter. And finally, if need be, I can ("Cancel notification"). So this appears to be everything I need. I'm currently looking at this option and trying to figure out how to actually get this working.

So there is my progress over the last few hours researching each of these options. I am hoping you can help me better understand how I may be misunderstanding the above options as this seems to me a very common use-case. Perhaps I am just not googling the question correctly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Unity has a build-in solution for this case (Local Notifications) : (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.0/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's a likelihood that you'll need to cancel a significant percent of the notifications you send, you should use local notifications. That way you can easily schedule and cancel them locally without making any network requests. Also, this solution works for offline devices which is great for games (played on planes, etc...)